# Encrypt and decrypt a password and share over http

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have received a strange requirement (as I find it a security threat) but somehow I have to finish it...

The requirement is sending a password over the https. What encryption and decryption method I should use while exchanging the password??

It is a web application. Password is not going to be stored in the database.

Comment: https is already encrypted, so you can send it in clear.

Comment: As Henry says Https is already encrypted, but, if you want to encrypt the password use MD5

Comment: @Sapikelio MD5 is a message digest, you can't encrypt with it. It was used for password hashes a long time ago, but it has been considered unsafe for several years already.

Comment: @Sapikelio Whatever your goal is: Password and MD5 do not go together. If you want to store and compare use scrypt, If you want to transport it plainly, MD5 will destroy that. Whenever you feel MD5 is the solution to your password needs, scrypt is what you should have used.

Comment: https does not save you from man in the middle attacks, so even if it seems to be encrypted data can still be read when someone attacks some node on the way. So it is better to encrypt it. Go with the private-public key, or if this is not a way for you go use something easier, maybe Diffie hellman key exchange.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. Please describe what you want to achieve with that. Why do you want to send the password? What does the receiving end do with it?

Comment: @Nadir https is not (protocol wise) open to MITM. As long as you have proper certification chains, no one can have a certificate for the target domain except the owner. Actual situations might differ, depending on the context.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Thxs for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many ways, but the main hint is "DO NOT WRITE YOUR OWN!"

the best way would be to have Public Private Key,

You take the message, and Encrypt it with the destination user's Public Key, and sign the message with your private key.

Then at the other end, the person can Verify your signature with your public key, and then decrypt it with their private key getting the unencrypted message.

This is long winded and usually passwords are never stored either. 
What is the purpose for sending the password? If it is say for logging into a SSO server then why not pass only the Encrypted password across.

So you say get the MD5 Hash of the password + a hidden phrase, Send the resulting hash to the other side, who then compare it to the same but from the entry in their end. There are ways to authenticate people without sending passwords. OpenID uses exactly that, you login to Facebook and then when a site asks for verification of who you are (login with facebook) it sends your email and a token that is registered on your browser (if you are logged into facebook already) or prompts you for your password on the Facebook site.

Then it passes back a small packet of data containing your email address, name and a token. this token is now the login token for that site (as it uses the sites id as part of the token) allowing you to get into the site without having to login again (until the token is expired)

so at no point does the website get your Facebook password as they just get the auth token.

Comment: You should not use MD5 for this purpose. Its broken, security wise, use scrypt instead.

Comment: it was just a suggestion, I was using it as a suggestion of a way to not send the password across the wire

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use the password for authentication purposes.

HTTPS, if done correctly, will protect your transport sufficiently. If you have no option to mask the password, you can rely on the transport security of HTTPS.

If you can, you should use [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) to mask the password before sending it over the network and again before storing it in the database.

There are ready to use scrypt libraries for java (and javascript which you could use on the client side) . Do not code it yourself.

This way the actual password never leaves the client and whoever could listen to the connection can make nothing of it. Even if some attacker would get hold of your database, he could not calculate the actual password.

DO NOT use MD5 for this, because then an attacker who gained access to the stored passwords can calculate the original password from it. [MD5 is unsafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) for this purpose.

Comment: But SCrypt is a reversible encryption, MD5 and similar hashes are one way encryptions

Comment: @TheresaForster No. Its not. Not at all, ever. Please read the functioning of that system.

Comment: @TheresaForster I recommend a read of this http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/ post on security.SEs blog about all this. They bring it to the point far better then I can.